# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in Ubuntu

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have seen many posting this issue in SO. I have gone through those posts and tried out the suggested methods, but unfortunately could not help me resolve the issue.

Here is my problem:

```
public class runme {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("example");
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    System.out.println(example.fact(4));


  }
}
```

Error:

```
anu@anu-desktop:~/Desktop/swigtest/new$ java runme
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no example in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at runme.<clinit>(runme.java:5)
    Could not find the main class: runme. Program will exit.
```

The example library is in the same path as the *runme.java*. Why do I get this error then? I am working from Ubuntu OS.

Any help which would help me resolve this is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I have attached my files [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-2RQZcQbc7NSzdGZVN3QU1kZlU)

Comment: I removed the C tag since it doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: @maba he may have stripped the code to show us only the relevant part (library loading).

Comment: @maba Your comment is not constructive.

Comment: I removed my old comments since they seem to have been non constructive and I apologize for that.

Comment: Sorry, I have not revealed the entire scenario. I am following the basic SWIG tutorials and was just blindly following the sample snippet they have provided. I was using the runme.java example provided [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#running_swig)

Comment: @user845279 My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010070/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-ubuntu/11010482#11010482) is constructive.

Comment: If your using Linux(Ubuntu terminal), Then please have a look on http://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.in/2017/07/java-jni-and-cc-from-command-line.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) say that *The manner in which a library name is mapped to the actual system library is system dependent*, in my experience `loadLibrary`'s relative path refers to the *working* directory (after which it checks all other defined and system-dependent paths).

If unsure about the working directory, check what `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns.

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir") returns the path in which my class file and the library exist

Comment: Is there surely a file called `example` in that directory? Any chance that it would be `example.so` - usually dynamic libraries are named that way in Linux?

Comment: yes, example is there. it is an executable. My code is [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-2RQZcQbc7NSzdGZVN3QU1kZlU)

Comment: It shouldn't be an executable! It should be a "Dynamically linked shared object library", i.e. `.so` (as opposed to `.a`, which are static libraries). See e.g. [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) for how to compile `.so`s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `java.library.path` property to include the path of your library. Or copy it to a location already in the path.

Comment: I have set the path of the folder in which the library resides using the export PATH=/path/to/my/libs:$PATH command and have confirmed whether this library is in the path using echo $PATH command. Still it gives me the issue.

Comment: On ubuntu, java.library.path is based on LD_LIBRARY_PATH, not PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your program like this:

```
$> java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/my/libs runme
```

Where `/path/to/my/libs` should be changed to where you really have your `.so` file(s).

---

**Edit**

I installed `openjdk-6-jdk` on my virtual Ubuntu machine to see where include files are.

Try this to get your `libexample.so`:

```
$> gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall example_wrap.c -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/linux
$> gcc -shared -o libexample.so example_wrap.o
```

Then check that the file has been created...

Now you just have to call

```
$> java runme
```

The `-Djava.library.path` is not needed if the `.so` file is in the working directory.

Comment: `anu@anu-desktop:~/Desktop/swigtest/new$ java -Djava.library.path=/home/anu/Desktop/swigtest/new runme
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no example in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
 at runme.<clinit>(runme.java:5)
Could not find the main class: runme. Program will exit.
anu@anu-desktop:~/Desktop/swigtest/new$ 
` Why this occurs still?

Comment: According to another answer here you have your lib files here `/home/anu/Desktop/swigtest/new/lib/linux32`. So that is what you should add to the `-Djava.library.path`. Try to locate the `libexample.so` and point there.

Comment: this is my path /home/anu/Desktop/swigtest/new . Since Ilan Tal told "with the addition of /lib/linux32", I just appended it to my path to check his suggestion

Comment: According to your [code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-2RQZcQbc7NSzdGZVN3QU1kZlU/edit) you don't have an `.so` file. You have created an executable called `example` and that won't work. Try to run the `gcc -c example_wrap.c  -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/linux` command again. Don´t forget the `-c`. Then again run `ld -G example_wrap.o  -o libexample.so`.

Comment: My last comment was taken from the swig site and was actually made for solaris but I updated my answer to make it work for Ubuntu.

Comment: `anu@anu-desktop:~/Desktop/swigtest/new$ gcc -c example_wrap.c -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/linux
example_wrap.c:135: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
anu@anu-desktop:~/Desktop/swigtest/new$`  Not sure if this happens for some obvious reasons!!

Comment: Look at my edited answer. If you are using Ubuntu then the include files are in a different location.

Comment: I got libexample.so created with the help of your commands,thanks, but still when I run java runme, I get "no example in java.library.path" . i even tried giving the full name of library , then it gives "no libexample in java.library.path" !! I checked whether the folder containg .so is in the path using echo $PATH and it is there in the path. So, unfortunately, still no output!

Comment: Try again with `java -Djava.library.path=xxx runme`. The name of library is `example` not `libexample`.

Comment: A bit more progress..it seems library is loaded `/Desktop/new$ java -Djava.library.path=/home/linux/Desktop/new runme
java: symbol lookup error: /home/linux/Desktop/new/libexample.so: undefined symbol: fact`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on Ubuntu and solved it using a bat file

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/lib/linux32
./fiji-linux
```

The object which needs to be set is LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I set it to the local directory with the addition of /lib/linux32. The next line runs my program.

Comment: like this? `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/anu/Desktop/swigtest/new/lib/linux32` . It does not work this way also!!

Comment: I'm sure that you are aware that you have to put your library into a subdirectory called lib/linux32. We chose to do it this way since it would allow a different library for linux64, win32 etc. It worked very well for me. My fiji-linux is at the level of $PWD, i.e. 2 levels above

Comment: I should also mention that the ./fiji-linux is important since the export goes out of scope when the bat file ends.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add/append the path to your shared library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH like :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path_to_folder_where_your_shared_library_is
```